# How to modify this C++ Makefile to make multiple binaries with same sources files but from differents main.cpp

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

Currently, i have a pretty cool generic C++ makefile that can make only one binary from multiple source files and headers. It's all-sufficient. I would like to know how to modify it in order to generate 2 binaries. Only the mains.cpp would be different. The headers are the same too. The source files are the same. I think for sure it's possible and I'd even wonder if a loop trough exec and binaries (EXEC files) exists to generate more than 2 binaries (with same sources file). I
don't master enough the GNU makefile language to know that. Thx a lot. I just sure that i have to add a .all rule with my 2 binaries but nothing after.
Look at this :

```
# sources (*.cpp)
SRC  := sources
# headers (*.cpp)
INC  := include
MAIN := kwic_personnel.cpp
EXEC := kwic
# second binary here
MAIN2 := other.cpp
EXEC2 := other

# main file is in current directory or in sources file but here the main files are in out of
# sources file for sure
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(MAIN))","")
    sources := $(MAIN) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
else
    sources := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
endif
# obj files
objects := $(sources:.cpp=.o)
# dep files
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -I $(INC) -MMD -MP -g -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -Weffc++ -Werror

# OS name
UNAME := $(shell uname -s)

# NOT SURE ABOUT THAT FOR MAC OS
# if linux
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)

    LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    LDLIBS   := -lcurl

# else but mac OS
else
    CXXFLAGS += -D OSX
    LDFLAGS  := -stdlib=libstdc++
endif

# linking
$(EXEC) : $(objects)
    @echo "Generation du fichier executable..."
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
    $(RM) $(objects) $(deps)
    @echo "Compilation réussie !"

# compilation of cpp files
$(SRC)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

# remove exec
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(EXEC)

# dependencies
-include $(deps)
```

Comment: Is it not an option to use CMake?

Comment: No i prefer to write my own makefiles.